# Touch-compatible JS quick navigation scrubber?

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

In long lists on iOS there exists a quick navigation "scrubber" on the right-hand side that you can brush your finger across to quickly jump from one item to the next, e.g. in the Music app if you have enough music available you'll see ABCD... allowing you to quickly jump to that letter of the alphabet in your list.

Does anyone know of a library or plugin to recreate this touch-based behavior on a website using anchor tags?

If not, are there any recommended approaches? My current thoughts are to disable touch events for the anchors if possible and capture touchbegin and touchmove on the parent div, then compare the coordinates of the touch with the coordinates of the anchor tags and fire off artificial 'click' events to cause the navigation.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/desmosinc/scrubber

> Simple, attractive html+js scrubber control.
>
> Tested in recent versions of Firefox, Chrome, Safari, and IE9+. Works
>   with mouse events and touch events.